# R: how to plot a cox regression model survival curves (treated vs control curves) using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a cox model in R that shows time to diabetes.
The formula is:

```
model <- coxph(Surv(days_followed,$outcome_status) ~exposure_status +  
          + age + gender + start_follow_date, method="breslow")
```

I'd now like to plot the adjusted survival curves using Ggplot2.  TWO curves, one for the treatment group and one for the control group.

So it's like Kaplan-Meier, except that the curves are adjusted for age, gender, start follow date, etc.

Can someone help me do this?

Comment: I would have expected this to throw an error from the `$` in the Surv argument. Should have provided a dataset so a proper demonstration could be attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some functions for this, if you look it up. For example, the ggsurv function from the [GGally](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/) package seems to do this. You can find a tutorial on using this function [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/07/creating-good-looking-survival-curves-the-ggsurv-function/).

Also, with some knowledge of ggplot2, you can adapt the code of the function to however it suits you better.